# How to Determine a Common Element in a Set of Tuples - Python

Tags: python, set, tuples

Say I have a set of tuples, with each tuple containing two integers.

```
mySet = ((1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5))
```

What would be the best way to find a **common element** from tuples?

For this case **output** will be :

```
3
```

Comment: Can you fail fast here? If 3 were not present in the second tuple, do you return false?

Comment: What if there are two numbers contained in each tuple, like `{(1, 3), (3, 1)}`? Do you want the result to be `{1, 3}` or either one of `1` or `3` arbitrarily, or an error, or…? (For that matter, what do you want the result to be when _no_ number is contained in each tuple?)

Comment: @rtindru If 3 were not present in the third tuple, then yes return False or None. Just any way to indicate that such a number doesn't exist.

Comment: @abarnert In my scenario such tuples wouldn't exist. All tuples found in the set would be ordered from lowest to highest, would never contain equal numbers, and there will never be two or more tuples that have the same contents despite ordering.

Comment: Plus 1 to abarnerts questions. Also how big a concern is performance?

Comment: @rtindru Performance isn't that important for my scenario, as I will only see integers ranging from 0 to 15 most likely, and the tuples represent multiple unique ways in which you can pick two numbers from that range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick solution.

*Edited to include genexpr instead of list comprehension*

```
mySet = {(1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)}
mySet = (set(tup) for tup in mySet)

print(set.intersection(*mySet))

# {3}
```

Comment: If the set could be huge, you might want to use a genexpr or map instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehension is more of a pythonic way than map, but genexpr would be better in that case, yes.

Comment: They're both pretty pythonic—map has been in the language even longer than comprehensions,, and when what you're applying to each object happens to be a ready-made function (rather than some arbitrary expression that you'd have to wrap up as a function to pass to map), it can be shorter, more readable, and more efficient (although the small constant performance difference rarely matters). I usually lean toward genexprs, but in this case I think I'd use `set.intersection(*map(set, mySet))`.

Comment: Agreed, map in this case is even more elegant than `*(set(item) for item in mySet)`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using converting nested tuples to set and calculating intersection of each.

```
from functools import reduce

def common_elements(s):
    return reduce(set.intersection, map(set, s))

>>> common_elements({(1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)})
>>> {3}
>>> common_elements({(1, 1), (1, 4), (3, 5)})
>>> set()
```

Timeit benchmark

```
$ python -m timeit -s "from functools import reduce" -s "s = {(1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)}" "reduce(set.intersection, map(set, s))"
$ 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "from functools import reduce" -s "s = {(0,1) for _ in range(100)}" "reduce(set.intersection, map(set, s))"
$ 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.5 usec per loop
```